# Ingest mobile events data into hdfs

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, flume

I have a mobile app that generates events frequently and there are millions of users who will use this app.
What's the best way to capture these events and persist them into hdfs for later analysis?

Answer (score 1):

As I assume from your tags, you are inclined to use Kafka and Flume with Kafka source and HDFS Sink. Your mobile app can publish data to Kafka topic and then by using Kafka source or Kafka channel (in case you do not need to use interceptors) you can consume these events and write to HDFS sink. Kafka is scalable so you don't have to worry about handling a high rate of events. However, I would suggest you use HBase as data storage. It will allow you later access each event with O(1) times. This can be done with HBase Sink. Check out this [article](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/03/building-benchmarking-and-tuning-syslog-ingest-architecture/) from Cloudera blog.

Comment: Mobile Apps cannot produce events directly for kafka I guess(you cann't run kafka source on mobile apps of all the users)
Will the flow be like: mobile apps -> web server -> kafka -> HBase

Comment: All you need is to write is `KafkaProducer` which can be easily done in Java [javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html). But web server option is also ok if it is scalable. Or you can use Flume HTTP Source and Kafka Sink.

Comment: how flume will help?

Comment: Well you will not have to implement web server by yourself, which will need to contain Kafka producer. It is also tested in production. Check out link mentioned above.